# Creating menu with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<li><div class="link" id="contentLink1"><a href="link1.html" target="_blank">Link 1</a></div></li>

<li><div class="link" id="contentLink2"><a href="link2.html" target="_blank">Link 2</a></div></li>
```

I am generating these links through my DB and I want to add `link2` within `link1` to create nested navigation I have to inject some jQuery to create the nested navigation.

For that I have tried grab the `link2` html  and put it after `link1` html but did not work. Can anyone help or suggest another solutions from which I can create nested navigation through jquery.

```
var link2 = $('#link2').parent().html(); 

var link1 = $('link').after();

link1 = link2;

console.log(link1);
```

I was just playing around to see weather the `link2` contents get copied inside the `link1` html content but did not get it work.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this fiddle. You will have to add some CSS to it though.
Also, I am not sure why you are adding the link inside a div, doesn't seem necessary to me.
[Updated the code snippet for a smoother effect on the mouseenter/leave and added some css]

```js
$('#contentLink1').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $('.submenu').css('display', 'flex');
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $('.submenu').css('display', 'none'); 
  }
});

$('.submenu').append('<li><div class="link" id="contentLink2"><a href="link2.html" target="_blank">Link 2</a></div></li>');
```

```css
.submenu {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.submenu li .link {
  background-color: #ccc;
} 

.link {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <div class="link" id="contentLink1">
    <a id="link1" href="link1.html" target="_blank">Link 1</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
     
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```